# Producing a plotted graph in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I need help in getting a plot graph generated as per the below requirement please. I am a novice and seek help.

Produce a simple graph – 1 graph with 3 plotted lines on it – whereby the axes accommodate full and accurate spatial dimensions.  Not just accommodating the supplied raw data points evenly across the axis .

```
# of lines/#of PO's  5 PO's  10 PO's  20 PO's   50 PO's
4 lines              8 min   16 min   32 min    80 min
8 lines              10 min  18 min   35 min    92 min
12 lines             14 min  24 mins  40 min    104 min
```

Data for graph:

[image: Data for grpah]

Axes = PO’s AND minutes.  Plotted lines = each of the 3 line numbers scenarios.

Comment: The data for the graph is in the attached image file.

Answer (score 0):

The table looks good, but you need to type the values as numbers instead of text.

Use `8` instead of `8 mins`, etc.

Then select the table and choose the diagram you want to use from `Insert` → `Charts` →.

See below for how it looks:

[image: Screenshot of my solution]